# GA4 Events Not Appearing in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

We are using GTM to track a custom GA4 event when the user clicks on in-house ads on a website. The events are showing up in the GA4 event reports but they are not showing up when querying the analytics events_intraday tables using BigQuery.

This is the query we are using:

```
select *
from `XXX.XXX.events_intraday_*` Analytics
where Analytics.event_name = 'ad_click'
```

However, events named ad_click are showing in the Engagement > Events report in GA4.

All other events are showing up in the BigQuery data such as page_view, scroll, session_start, etc. using similar queries:

```
select *
from `XXX.XXX.events_intraday_*` Analytics
where Analytics.event_name = 'page_view'
```

Is there something specific in GA4 that prevents certain events from being sent to the BigQuery data sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that the ad_click event is a predefined/reserved event that is used by GA4 for "Publisher events coming from AdMob via the Google Mobile Ads SDK".

I changed to using click_ad instead and it now flows through to BigQuery correctly.